# How to limit plot to show top 15 most important features

Tags: python, matplotlib

From a Logistic Regression ('lrmodel') I want to plot the feature importance given by it but I want to limit it to top 15 most relevant, how can I do this? I have the following code:

```
feature_importance = abs(lrmodel.coef_[0])
feature_importance = 100.0 * (feature_importance / feature_importance.max())
sorted_idx = np.argsort(feature_importance)
pos = np.arange(sorted_idx.shape[0]) + .5

featfig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 40))
featax = featfig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
featax.barh(pos, feature_importance[sorted_idx], align='center')
featax.set_yticks(pos)
featax.set_yticklabels(np.array(X.columns)[sorted_idx], fontsize=16)
featax.set_xlabel('Relative Feature Importance')

plt.tight_layout()   
plt.show()
```

[Plot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZubHn.png)

Thanks!

Comment: No data makes it difficult to provide solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `argsort` you get the indices for a sorted list in *ascending* order. Since you want the top 15, reverse the list by `[::-1]` and then plot them as follows:

```
pos = np.arange(15) + .5
featax.barh(pos, feature_importance[sorted_idx][::-1][0:15], align='center')
featax.set_yticklabels(np.array(X.columns)[sorted_idx][::-1][0:15], fontsize=16)
```

Comment: This only gives me the first 15, not sorted by importance.

Comment: But your are already plotting sorted values of the features using `feature_importance[sorted_idx]`. Add more information/data in your question together with the plot your are getting otherwise it's difficult to help you

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I added an image of the output of the plot.